# find partial terms in symbolic expressions in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector of symbolic expressions like this in matlab:

```
eqn = k*r*t0*Lp+k*t0*(r*Li+La)+In -Ic;
```

I'd like to find the expression(k*r).Any idea how can I do that? Thanks!
simple example：

```
a+b+c+d = 0;
```

I'd like to find the expression(a+c),then:

```
a+c = -(b+d);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to isolate `k*r`, so.... do that!

```
syms k r t0 Lp Li La In Ic
eqn = k*r*t0*Lp+k*t0*(r*Li+La)+In -Ic==0;
isolate(expand(eqn),k*r) % for some reason this case did not work without expand()

ans =
 
k*r == -(In - Ic + La*k*t0)/(Li*t0 + Lp*t0)
```